# C++17. Dealing with template parameters that are related using auto . Difficulties with code ordering

Tags: c++, templates, auto

I'm creating a class template which takes 2 template parameters but are related.
One instantiation will be for a mysql database. The template is initialised with type MYSQL and
member functions will return MYSQL_RES *. 
This works nicely if I create a template with 2 parameters 
eg

```
template<class T,class R> class foo
```

but as the classes are related, when type T is specified, type R is known. Is there any way to
code this?

Using auto I can get this to work eg.

```
template<class T> class foo{
 public:
auto bar();
};
```

with a member function specialisation given like

```
 template<> auto foo<MYSQL>::bar(){MYSQL_RES *r;return r;};
```

but then run into problems with code ordering. ie template<> auto foo::bar 
has to be implemented before use and not in a separate cpp file.

I've tried doing a forward declaration
eg

```
template<> auto foo<MYSQL_RES>::bar();
```

but this doesn't work.

Does anyone have a graceful way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" mean? What errors are you getting?

Comment: When you say "type R is known", do you have access to it? Could you expose it in the MYSQL implementation like this? `class MYSQL {public: using RESTYPE = MYSQL_RES;};` Then you can use `T::RESTYPE bar();`

Comment: If, as you say, "type R is known" then it has no business being a template parameter. The template can simply derive what it should be, perhaps using forward declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create trait to help you:

```
template<class T> struct myFooTrait;

template<class T> class foo
{
public:
    using R = typename myFooTrait<T>::type;
    R bar();
};

class MYSQL;
class MYSQL_RES;

template<> struct myFooTrait<MYSQL>
{
    using type = MYSQL_RES *;
};

template<>
auto foo<MYSQL>::bar() -> R { MYSQL_RES *r = /*..*/;return r;}

// Other specializations...
```

Comment: Brillant, it now works. Thank you.  Had to change    using R = myFooTrait<T>::type;    to      R = typename myFooTrait<T>::type.        Now  googling traits to see how they work

Comment: @metelko Consider accepting the answer if it helped you to solve your problem.